# Linear operator image subspace chain

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

How to prove the proposition: $A: V \to V$ is a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V $, if $Im(A^p)=Im(A^{p+1})$,then $Im(A^{p+1})=Im(A^{p+2})$

The "Kernel" version is simple but I am stuck at the Image version of this proposition.

Comment: Hint: $\mbox{Im}(AB)=A(\mbox{Im}(B))$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First direction:**

$A^{p+2} \subseteq A^{p+1}$:

If $v = A^{p+2}(w)$ for some $w \in V$, then for some $w' \in V$

> $$ v = A(A^{p+1}(w)) = A(A^p(w')) = A^{p+1}(w') \in Im(A^{p+1})$$

**Other direction:**

$A^{p+1} \subseteq A^{p+2}$:

If $ v = A^{p+1}(w)$ for some $w \in V$, then for some $w' \in V$

> $$v = A(A^p(w)) = A(A^{p+1}(w')) = A^{p+2}(w') \in Im(A^{p+2}) $$

**Shorter version**

The above is instructive, but there's a one-liner to this, using the hint that states $Im(A\circ B) = A(Im(B))$:

> $$ Im(A^{p+2}) = Im(A \circ A^{p+1}) = A(Im(A^{p+1})) = A(Im(A^p)) = Im(A^{p+1}) $$